# In AWS, policy to deny permissions to delete volume in particular availability zone in region in EC2 with JSON to IAM user

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, policy

write policy i JSON, which will deny to delete volume in ap-southeast-1a(availability zone) in Singapore region.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-1:*:volume/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:availabilityzone": "ap-southeast-1a"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```